# Java Script: Add the random rolls of two dice for "n" rolls

Tags: javascript, random

I am working on adding together the random rolls of a pair of dice for `n` rolls as defined by user.  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dice.css">
        <script>
//supposed to give 2 random numbers
function roll() { 
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var Total = x + y;
}

// ask for user to put how many times they want to roll the two dice
function myinput() { 
    var NumRoll = prompt("Please enter the number of times you wish to roll");

    if  (NumRoll <= 0 ) 
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "You entered an invalid number enter number between 1-100";
    else if ( NumRoll >100 )
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "You enter an invalid number enter number between 1-100";
    else 
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = "Rolling the dice " + NumRoll + "  times";
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="wrong"> </p>
        <p1 id="right"></p1>
        <p>Click to roll dice</p>

        <button onclick="myinput(); roll()">Press</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so the user ask to roll the dice 23 times, the dice will roll 23 times addingall the numbers it rolled together I'm not surehow to connect the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function roll(repeat) { 
 var repeat = repeat || 1;
 var Total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < repeat; i++){
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    Total += x + y;
 }
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = Total;
}

document.getElementById('rollTrigger').addEventListener('click',function(){
 roll(document.getElementById('numRoll').value);
});
```

```html
<input id="numRoll" type="text" placeholder="Number of time to roll the dice">
<br><a href="#" id="rollTrigger">Roll the dice!</a>
<br>
<span id="total"></span>
```

Add an argument to your roll() function and wrap your var x, y into a for loop. Then pass the value of the input to the roll function :)

See the jsfiddle for more details

https://jsfiddle.net/bzdgz6ac/